# Virtual Pageviews in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am posting this question again with detailed description. Hope this time I will get valuable advice from Experts!!

I want to create Google Analytic funnel for Registration Page(On successful Registration, Url doesn't change). I have created a virtual pageview tag in GTM

[image: Please see attached imageenter image description here]

and pushed following Datalayer on Success:

```
dataLayer.push({
'event':'VirtualPageview',
'virtualPageURL':'/virtual/login/',
'virtualPageTitle' : ' Registration Page'
});
```

Trigger

[image]

When I am debugging the getting message: Tags are not fired on this page but on the left side event is showing "Virtual pageview".

Can Anyone help/guide me?

Comment: To answer you question. Your Event you send via the datalayer is the following: 'event':'VirtualPageview - but the listener looks different. "VRegistrationSuccesfully". Set your trigger to a event called "VirtualPageview". This should do it.

What I don´t realy get is what you want to do. I think it would be easier to send a Event to GA to track the succesful registration -> For Example = EventCategory = Success, Trigger = {{YourURL}}

Comment: I think it would be easier to send a Event to GA to track the succesful registration -> For Example = EventCategory = Success, Trigger = {{YourURL}} –

I have two forms on a single page i.e.: Login and Registration. And, I want to create funnel for both. Is it possible with your method? If yes, Can you please help me?

Comment: I would recomend to decide between events/virtual pageviews based on your reporting needs and not based on "I think it's easier". Both options are easy to implement, just make sure you are aware that with Events you won't be able to create funnels in your reporting. Both options have different pros/cons

Comment: As Daniel mentioned the only problem I can see is with the name of your event. If you rename it to: "dataLayer.push({ 'event':'VRegistrationSuccesfully', ..." it should work just fine.

Comment: Matus and  Daniel. Thank you so much for your help. I have changed the trigger to "VirtualPageview". It is working :)

Comment: One more help needed with this: I am tracking these virtual pageviews in GA  by creating funnels. See here: http://oi65.tinypic.com/21e9rwp.jpg. But results are not showing even after tags are successfully fired. http://oi63.tinypic.com/2coqzxx.jpg 

Is there anything wrong here? Or should I need to wait for results?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your query and noticed that the event name in your trigger is wrong. Please change event name to "VirtualPageview" and it will work. You can read more about vpvs here: http://stackbug.com/google-analytics/how-can-you-generate-a-virtual-pageview-on-event/